# doubts on optimistic concurrency control of creating item

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-sdk-python

I noticed `ContainerProxy` of `cosmosdb` had a few methods that contains `etag` and `match_condition` parameters which I understand is for optimistic concurrency control. But one thing I do not understand is why `create_item` also has `etag` and `match_condition`, see the link [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.containerproxy?view=azure-python#create-item-body--populate-query-metrics-none--pre-trigger-include-none--post-trigger-include-none--indexing-directive-none----kwargs-). The way how optimistic concurrency control works is we retrieve `etag` from a record and use it to check whether the record is being changed during the process of updating. But for creating a new record, there is no `etag` to retrieve. How do we really use `etag` and `match_condition` in `create_item`?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK is just a nice wrapper around the Cosmos REST API. According to the REST API description the [create a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document) operation does not use an `etag` and as you said there's no reason why it would. Could be a leftover from writing reusable code for the different operations.